# Ruby: Kernel#` Permission denied to run command

Tags: ruby

In trying to learn about Ruby execution methods, I found this blog post on five ways to run commands in Ruby  http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/

The author creates a file err.rb, which outputs two lines, one on STDOUT, the other on STDERR

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "out"
STDERR.puts "error"
```

The first way he tries to run it is with Kernal#` (backticks)

```
 >> `./err.rb`

      err
=> "out\n"
```

The point this illustrates is that when run with backticks

> ```
> STDERR is output, but not captured
> STDOUT is captured
> ```

When I tried to duplicate this on my system, I got a permission error

```
localhost:sites mike$ `./err.rb`
-bash: ./err.rb: Permission denied
```

I tried sudo `./err.rb` with no change.

I can run `ruby err.rb` but that produces a different result than what the author got. Namely by running ruby err.rb I get

```
  out
  error
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting a permission error trying to run it with backticks, and also generally what the whole purpose of running it with backticks is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add permission to execute, use "chmod +x that_file_name"
to execute using format "./file" the 'file' need to have execute permission

It runs when you ruby because ruby has execute permission and it simply read that file.

Try this

```
localhost:sites mike$ chmod +x err.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the file executable, which you can do from your shell:

```
chmod +x err.rb
```

Then you can call it from a shell as

```
./err.rb
```

or from IRB as

```
`./err.rb`
```

You could also execute `ruby` on it:

```
`ruby err.rb`
```

Here's a [good resource](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands) for the different backticks, system, and exec methods too.